# How do I onboard a submerchant in Braintree? [PHP SDK]

Tags: php, braintree, marketplace, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

In **PHP**, I am developing an application that is going to use the Braintree Marketplace functionality - for users within my platform to be able to handle escrow transactions for projects they post. I understand the code on how to do actual transactions, but I am having issues on the **sub-merchant** process and where that necessary code is supposed to go.

I have looked extensively on how to [onboard sub-merchants](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/onboarding/php) with the code from their documentation, but where am I supposed to put all this? On its own separate page? The only coding example is the very basics here on [Github](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_example). I need to be able to create these sub-merchants so that I can test escrow within their Sandbox.

Comment: The scope on this is a bit broad for SO, you might have better luck emailing in your questions to the Braintree support staff: support@braintreepayments.com

Comment: I've been doing that for a week -- I just need to get a grip on the file structure and where the code is supposed to go, as the documentation only provides an example of basic transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I was trying to do was a limitation of Braintree itself. At that time, you were not able to test escrow transactions within their Sandbox. Not sure if that has changed over the past year.

**For those looking for a much better payments API, check out [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) instead.**